# Distinguishability disparity, elementary counting

Tags: probability, combinatorics, intuition

Let $m,n$ be given positive integers, $m \geq n$. I am interested in the ratio of the number of solutions to $x_1+\dots+x_n=m$ in *positive* integers to the number of solutions to $x_1+\dots+x_n=m$ in *nonnegative* integers. A stars-and-bars argument that can be found elsewhere on MSE tells us that the former is

$${m-1 \choose n-1}$$

while the latter is

$${n+m-1 \choose n-1}.$$

Thus the fraction that I aimed to compute at the beginning is $\frac{{m-1 \choose n-1}}{{n+m-1 \choose n-1}}=\frac{(m-1)!m!}{(m-n)!(n+m-1)!}$. So that's fine.

Now let's suppose the $m$ objects are now distinguishable (the $n$ boxes were already distinguishable in the previous formulation).  I actually am not so interested to actually compute the ratio in this case. For my purpose it suffices to notice that the fraction of the configurations in which any one fixed box is occupied is now $1-\left ( \frac{n-1}{n} \right )^m$, and so the probability that all the boxes are occupied is at least $1-n \left ( \frac{n-1}{n} \right )^m$. As $m \to \infty$ this converges to $1$ exponentially fast.

But in the indistinguishable formulation, the ratio converges to $1$ far slower: it is asymptotically something like $1-n^2/m$.

Where is the discrepancy? In particular, why isn't the number of ways to do both things in the distinguishable case just $m!$ times the number of ways to do it in the indistinguishable case, so that the ratios would agree? And why is the effect so drastic in the $m \to \infty$ limit?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the distinguishable case isn't just $m!$ times the number from the indistinguishable case is due to double counting.  Let's just consider the case where $n = 2$ and $m = 3$.  Consider the indistinguishable case of $x_1 = 2$ and $x_2 = 1$.  This corresponds to having $2$ balls in the first bin and $1$ ball in the second bin.

How many distinguishable cases correspond to this indistinguishable case?  It's just a matter of labeling the ball in the second bin, and thus there are $3$ choices for labeling, not $6 = 3!$.

Comment: Ah, now I see my problem. Because of the physical situation that I have in mind, I was visualizing the objects in a given bin as being stacked on top of each other. Thus, looking at your example case, I was implicitly allowing myself to distinguish between the two objects that you put into the first bin, by virtue of which one was on top and which one was on bottom. Does the situation simplify the way I anticipated if we allow for this level of distinguishability of configurations (i.e. where the order that we populated the bin matters)?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're asking.  What quantity are you interested in?

Comment: How many ways are there to allocate $m$ objects to $n$ bins when I can distinguish between the objects and can also distinguish between the order in which the objects entered the bins? It seems clear that this should be $n^m$, because such a configuration is exactly specified by the bin that you put the first object in, the bin that you put the second object in, etc. What's not so clear to me is whether this $n^m$ can be related back to these other quantities in a simple fashion.

Comment: For a similar example, we can count combinations by first counting permutations and then "forgetting about reorderings" by dividing by a factorial.